# "Choose to" vs "make a conscious decision"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrasing

How does the phrase "I choose to do X" compare against "I make a conscious decision to do X"?

Does the latter serve to underline the point, or does it seem redundant? Especially when compared to the simple phrasing of the first.

Comment: Can you give some context for this? Choosing can be done by flipping a coin, by asking someone else, by evaluating etc. Making a conscious decision is one way of choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former phrase does not indicate if the choice was thought out, it could be random choice.

The second phrase however suggests that the choices were well thought of and then a decision was made, there is a supportive argument to the result.

Example :

> I chose to learn coding.
>
> I made a conscious decision to learn coding, because it has good job prospects

The former phrase will be more useful if you add a supporting argument to it

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was floating through my mind, but I wasn't able to say it in as many words :)